# In-line math symbol convention

Tags: inline

I know it's much better to use `\[ \]` over `$$ $$` when typesetting math equations on their own line (I believe this is called display math?) But is it also inappropriate to use `$ $` for in-line math over `\( \)`? If so, what are the reasons? I find the latter much more cumbersome to type, so I'd only like to use it if there's a good reason.

Comment: By the way, (belated) [welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @PaulGessler Thank you! I'm trying to improve my Tex skills - I want my math homework to be gorgeous. And yes, it does appear to be a duplicate, thanks for the direction!

Comment: The `LaTeX` manuals recommend using `$...$` for in-line formula and `\[ ... \]` for displayed formula.